# Using a Geo Distance Function on ELKI

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, geospatial, dbscan, elki

I am using ELKI to mine some geospatial data (lat,long pairs) and I am quite concerned on using the right data types and algorithms. On the parameterizer of my algorithm, I tried to change the default distance function by a geo function (LngLatDistanceFunction, as I am using x,y data) as bellow:

```
params.addParameter (DISTANCE_FUNCTION_ID,  geo.LngLatDistanceFunction.class);
```

However the results are quite surprising: it creates clusters of a repeated point, such as the example bellow:

(2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043,  NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN), (2.17199922, 41.38190043, NaN)]

[This is an image](https://ladybug.no-ip.org/files/clusters_lonlat.png) of this example.

Whether I used a **non-geo** distance (for instance manhattan):

```
params.addParameter (DISTANCE_FUNCTION_ID,  geo.minkowski.ManhattanDistanceFunction.class);
```

,t[he output is much more reasonable](https://ladybug.no-ip.org/files/clusters_manhattan.png)

I wonder if there is something wrong with my code.

I am running the algorithm directly on the db, like this:

```
         Clustering<Model> result = dbscan.run(db);
```

And then iterating over the results in a loop, while I construct the convex hulls:

```
   for (de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.Cluster<?> cl : result.getAllClusters()) {
               if (!cl.isNoise()){
                     Coordinate[] ptList=new Coordinate[cl.size()];
                        int ct=0;               

                        for (DBIDIter iter = cl.getIDs().iter(); 
                                iter.valid(); iter.advance()) {
                                ptList[ct]=dataMap.get(DBIDUtil.toString(iter));                                                                                                                                            
                                ++ct;                                                                   
                        }       

                        GeoPolygon poly=getBoundaryFromCoordinates(ptList);
                        if (poly.getCoordinates().getGeometryType()==
                        "Polygon"){                                                     
                            out.write(poly.coordinates.toText()+"\n");
                        }                      
               }
            }
```

To map each ID to a point, I use a hashmap, that I initialized when reading the database.
The reason why I am adding this code, is because I suspect that I may doing something wrong regarding the structures that I am passing/reading to/from the algorithm.
I thank you in advance for any comments that could help me to solve this. I find ELKI a very efficient and sophisticated library, but I have trouble to find examples that illustrate simple cases, like mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `epsilon` value?

Geographic distance is in *meters* in ELKI (if I recall correctly); Manhattan distance would be in latitude + longitude *degrees*. For obvious reasons, these live on very different scales, and therefore you need to choose a different epsilon value.

In your previous questions, you used `epsilon=0.008`. For geodetic distance, 0.008 meters = 8 millimeter.

At epsilon = 8 millimeter, I am not surprised if the clusters you get consist only of duplicated coordinates. Any chance that above coordinates do exist multiple times in your data set?

Comment: You are totally right. The change **from degrees to meters** (a much more meaningfull unit, anyway) leads to the [correct results](https://ladybug.no-ip.org/files/clusters_250_350.png). It would be **really** helpfull if you could indicate the distance unit in the [documentation](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.6.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/distance/distancefunction/geo/LngLatDistanceFunction.html); by seeing the input coordinates as lat,long, I was tricked to think that the unit would be degrees... many thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have improved the documentation. And of course I hope to find the time of writing a tutorial; all the way to visualizing points using convex hulls or alpha shapes, with KML and Google Earth. But I'm always very busy.