# ELKI DBSCAN RESULT structure

Tags: dbscan, elki

I am not able to get points which are in each cluster returned by elki dbscan.

```
ArrayList<Clustering<?>> cs = ResultUtil.filterResults(result,
                Clustering.class);
        for (Clustering<?> c : cs) {
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("clusters: " + c.getAllClusters().size());
            for (de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.Cluster<?> cluster : c
                    .getAllClusters()) {
                System.out.println("\nclusters : " + cluster.getNameAutomatic()
                        + " , IsNoise:" + cluster.isNoise() + ", Size:"
                        + cluster.size());
```

Output is:

```
clusters: 4

clusters : Cluster , IsNoise:false, Size:240

clusters : Cluster , IsNoise:false, Size:374

clusters : Cluster , IsNoise:false, Size:4901

clusters : Noise , IsNoise:true, Size:211
```

I have gone through this [Running DBSCAN in ELKI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634614/running-dbscan-in-elki/23639300?noredirect=1#23639300)!. Still I am not able to get around to see the points in a cluster. I want to store it in an Array. What is the structure of cluster stored by elki?? I am stuck !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cluster.getDBIDs()` to get the cluster members.

To get the raw data, retrieve the objects from the original `Relation` you analyzed.

```
for (DBIDIter iter = cluster.getIDs().iter(); iter.valid(); iter.advance()) {
    DoubleVector obj = relation.get(iter);
```

Note that ELKI allows abstract analysis of data - e.g. when using a distance matrix. In such cases, you may not have a `DoubleVector` relation, but only object IDs. This is why cluster do not consist of vectors. They consists of a `DBIDs` collection, and in some cases of a cluster model such as a centroid vector.

Comment: Thank you very much That was a big help !!